# How can I change styling and test for every page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For each reload i want to change the text and also i want to change background color How can I do this?
I can also use PHP.  I thing for this coding PHP is not needed 
Following is the skeleton of my  code

**CSS**

```
.rotate
{
    background-color:#9C6;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTxt').html("hai");
});
```

**Html**

```
<div class="rotate" style="border: 1px red solid; height:100px; width:200px;">
   <span id="myTxt"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Background color of which element? What should be the color? Why not changing the `css` rule?

Comment: There is no form element in your posted markup.

Comment: you haven't specified a form here

Comment: this doesn't show the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a `array` of colors and text contents to dynamically change content and  text inside `div`

```
String colors = ["red","green","blue",....up to 11];
String text = ["Murali","Bobby","Candy"....up to 11];

var x = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
$('#myTxt').html(text[x]);
$(".rotate").css("backgroundColor",colors[x]);
```

Comment: sorry only displaying  the 10 color and text

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP in your HTML file:

```
<?php $colors = array("#f00", "#0f0", "#00f", "#c0c0c0", "#abcdef"); ?>
  <style>
    .rotate
    {
        background-color:<?php echo $colors[array_rand($colors)] ?>;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: hey great color got changed